# Top vertical align text.

Tags: css, position

Having trouble vertical top-aligning two simple text. For some reason there is a small gap ... tried padding, line-height etc, nothing. Any input helpful.

```
<span style="padding:0px;font-size: 48px;font-style: italic;font-weight: bold;"><span style="padding:0px;font-size: 30px;font-style: italic;vertical-align:text-top;">VITA</span>
```

VITA

https://jsfiddle.net/p64g800g/

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `font-size: 0px;` for the parent so that the space between the `span` has a `width` of 0px.

**Use this:**

```html
<div style="font-size: 0px;">
  <span style="font-size: 30px;font-style: italic;vertical-align:text-top;">VITA</span>
  <span style="font-size: 40px;font-style: italic;vertical-align:text-top;">VITA</span>
</div>
```

**Alternative:** Float the `<span>`

```css
span {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<span style="font-size: 30px;font-style: italic;">VITA</span>
<span style="font-size: 40px;font-style: italic;">VITA</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the line height on the second. I would wrap them in a div rather than another span, but didn't do that here since it may not be an option to you.

```css
.span1 {
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.span2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: italic;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
.span3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 39px;
  font-style: italic;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<span class="span1">
  <span class="span2">VITA</span>
  <span class="span3">VITA</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

A you can see, your `<span>` tags can't accept `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`. This is where you should start thinking about `display` property.

The `display` you need here is `inline-block`. With this property you can start moving your `<span>` elements vertically.

```html
<span style="padding: 0px;font-size: 48px;font-style: italic;font-weight: bold;">
    <span style="font-size: 30px;font-style: italic;vertical-align: text-top;display: inline-block">VITA</span>
    <span style="font-size: 40px;font-style: italic;vertical-align: text-top;display: inline-block;margin-top: -4px">VITA</span>
</span>
```